# jQuery file upload refreshing page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I saw this question, ["Show Open Dialog on a Button click"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051254/show-open-dialog-on-a-button-click):

> *'I have to show a Open Dialog box on a button click. Basically I have to upload a file, for this I am using FileUpload control, but I don’t want to show it to user instead I want to show a Button'*

And the answer was :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">      
   $(document).ready(function() {      
      $("#btn").click(function() {       
        $("#FileUpload1").click();         
       return false; 
      });         
   });  
   </script>   
   <style type="text/css">      
      .Class { visibility:hidden;}     
   </style> </head> <body>    
   <form id="form1" runat="server">  
   <div>       
      <asp:Button ID="btn"  runat="server" Text="Send File"/>   
      <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" CssClass="Class" runat="server" />
```

But i tried it and all it does is refreshing the page, anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Surely you can come up with a more descriptive title.

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML?

Comment: @Matt - What did you expected from a guy that names his classes "Class" ? Just kidding ;-)

Comment: @Dominic if you read it more carefully you'll see that it's not my code ;)

Comment: @Roy - Yeah I know, said I was kidding!! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "FileUpload1" is not the ClientID. Just look at the generated HTML source of your page and you will see that.

You should use something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $("#<%= btn.ClientID %>").click(function() {       
    $("#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>").click();         
      return false; 
  });         
});  
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried his code and it works perfectly. Do this.. Open the page.. click Send File button.. Press Ctrl+Shift+J and see what errors are listed.

Comment: Yeah, but now i'm getting HTML access denied :(

Answer (score 0):

All server-side controls (those with `runat="server"` attributes) have their IDs re-written by ASP.NET. Your IDs will actually look something like `ctl00_MainContent_btn`.

You can get around this by using `<%= btn.ClientID %>` server tags or by assigning a CSS class to your controls and referencing that class in JavaScript/jQuery.

**Edit:** You probably also need to make sure that your ASP button is not a submit button, which would cause the generated page to submit the form.

Comment: @RoyGavrielov, **what** isn't working? We need more information from you to help you fix your problems.

Comment: sorry, i replaced ("#btn") with ("<%= btn.ClientID %>") and ("#FileUpload1") with ("#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>") and still not working

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the new information? Are you getting any error messages? Have you tried using FireBug or debugging any C# code to narrow down the line that causes the refresh? Also, have you checked to make sure your ASP button isn't submitting the form to the page you're on?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a security risk, and I wouldn't be surprised if security prevented that from working.

Take a look at this [jQuery Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) plugin.

Comment: @ James i can't use it in my organization

Comment: You can't use what? A jQuery script?

Comment: You can't use any third party libraries? It's just a javascript file, not really a plugin you install...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to not go that route. If you want to avoid showing FileUpload control to user.. [use this](http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/).

Comment: @ mohib i can't use it in my organization

Answer (score 0):

make the client mode static to be able to access you controls like this

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="Class" runat="server" /> 
  <asp:Button ID="btn"  ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" Text="Send File"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page refreshes because the target of your form is implicitly the current page. You need to set the target of your form to be (for example) a hidden iframe:

```
<form id="my-form" action="url" target="form-target" method="post">
  <!-- your form here -->
</form>

<iframe id="form-target" name="form-target" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<script>
  // Assuming you are using jquery
  var form = $('#my-form'),
      iframe = $('#form-target');

  // create a function to be called each time the iframe loads
  iframe.load(function () {
    var responseText, iframeBody;

    // Get the response from the server. It will be in the body tag of your iframe
    iframeBody = $(this).contents().find('body');
    responseText = iframeBody.text().trim();
    // Don't continue until we actually have a response
    if (!responseText) return;
    // Clear the iframe's html so this function won't be called again for the same content
    iframeBody.html('');

    // do whatever you want with the response, for example JSON decode it
    response = JSON.parse(responseText);
  });
</script>
```